# Oracle SQL - How to join a single value to a multi-value column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a multi-value code column and I want to join it to a lookup table which has a single value code. The tables already exist so just a Select statement is ok.

My Query but it only matches columns with only 1 value:

```
select key, code, desc from <driving table> d 
left join <lookup table> l 
on ',' || d.code || ',' like '%,' || l.code || ',%'
```

CODE and DESC columns are Varchar

for example:

```
Driving table:
KEY | CODE 
001   1,2
002   1,2,3
003   2 

Lookup table:
CODE | DESC
 1     desc 1
 2     desc 2
 3     desc 3

Resulting output:
KEY | CODE | DESC
001    1     desc 1
001    2     desc 2
002    1     desc 1
002    2     desc 2
002    3     desc 3
003    2     desc 2
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in a string!

Comment: unfortunately... that's not up to me

Comment: If that is not up to you, that's a shame. But... did you even try to bring this up to your superiors, and they told you to shut up and to do as you are told? Or did you not even think of bringing it up to your bosses? Very often the latter is the case, not the former. (I am not saying that's necessarily your case, but in most cases it is.) If you need help in arguing your position, we can point you to overwhelming support for what is called First Normal Form in relational database data modeling.

Comment: Other than that, upon quick inspection your code looks right. Perhaps you have a data problem (meaning, the data is not in the exact format you think it is)? For example, might there be spaces after the commas, in the lists of values? Or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite inefficiently use `like` for this purpose:

```
select d.*, l.*
from driving d join
     lookup l
     on ',' || l.id || ',' like '%,' || d.code || ',%';
```

I would suggest, though, that you work on fixing the data model so you have a table with one row per `key` and `code`.